# Error while runningQueryInThanos -"duplicate series for the match group,many-to-many matching not allowed:matching labels must be unique on one side"

Tags: prometheus, promql, thanos

avg_over_time(test_gauge_http_client{}[1d]) * on(server_ip, client_ip, net_host_port, server_port) group_left(server_host_name, server_process_command, server_process_name, service_instance_id) label_replace(avg_over_time(test_gauge_http_server{}[1d]), "server_process_id", "$1", "server_process_id", "(.*)")

Error -

Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {client_ip="10.54.240.25", net_host_port="9090", server_ip="10.54.240.27", server_port="50051"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{client_ip="10.54.240.25", http_scheme="http", instance="127.0.0.1:9090", job="otel-collector", net_host_port="9090", receive="true", server_host_name="jfm-qnc-06", server_ip="10.54.240.27", server_port="50051", server_process_command="python3 host_server.py", server_process_id="1476894", server_process_name="python3", service_instance_id="127.0.0.1:9090", service_name="otel-collector", tenant_id="default-tenant", type="server"}, {client_ip="10.54.240.25", http_scheme="http", instance="127.0.0.1:9090", job="otel-collector", net_host_port="9090", receive="true", server_host_name="jfm-qnc-06", server_ip="10.54.240.27", server_port="50051", server_process_command="python3 host_server.py", server_process_id="1313284", server_process_name="python3", service_instance_id="127.0.0.1:9090", service_name="otel-collector", tenant_id="default-tenant", type="server"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

Error Image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OVya.png)

I tried the query by removing some labels but still its giving error.